# How to get the list of all the stemmed words along with its original formafter doing stemDocument in R

Tags: r, text-mining, tm, corpus, stemming

I am trying to get the list of all the stemmed words along with its original form.

here is an example

```
library(tm)
text <- c("Very Impressed with the shipping time, it arrived a few days earlier than expected", "it was very helpful","It was a wonderful experience")
corpus<-Corpus(VectorSource(text))
corpus<-tm_map(corpus,stemDocument)
```

I am looking for answer like this in data frame

```
 orginal_word   stemmed 
 Impressed      Impress 
 shipping        ship
 very            veri
 helpful         help
 wonderful       wonder
 experience      experi
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a little more efficient than @jazzurro's answer:

```
library("corpus")
text <- c("Very Impressed with the shipping time, it arrived a few days earlier than expected", "it was very helpful","It was a wonderful experience")
word <- text_types(text, collapse = TRUE, drop = stopwords_en, drop_punct = TRUE)
stem <- SnowballC::wordStem(word, "english")
data.frame(word, stem)
```

Result:

```
         word    stem
1     arrived   arriv
2        days     day
3     earlier earlier
4    expected  expect
5  experience  experi
6     helpful    help
7   impressed impress
8    shipping    ship
9        time    time 
10  wonderful  wonder
```

(The `text_types` function also accepts `tm` Corpus objects if that matters to you.)

Answer (score 0):

This may be something helpful for you. There is a function called `wordStem()` in the `SnowballC` package. Using it, you could do the following. Since I use `unnest_tokens()` in the `tidytext` package, I created a data frame first. The function splits the words and create a long-format data set. It seems that you want to remove stop words, so I did the using `filter()`. The final step is the crucial one for you. I used `wordStem()` in the `SnowballC` package to extract stems for the words remaining in the data. The outcome may not be exactly what you want. But I hope this will help you to some extent.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidytext)
library(SnowballC)

mydf <- data_frame(id = 1:length(text),
                   text = text)

data(stop_words)

mydf %>%
unnest_tokens(input = text, output = word) %>%
filter(!word %in% stop_words$word) %>%
mutate(stem = wordStem(word))

#      id       word    stem
#   <int>      <chr>   <chr>
# 1     1  impressed impress
# 2     1   shipping    ship
# 3     1       time    time
# 4     1    arrived   arriv
# 5     1       days     dai
# 6     1    earlier earlier
# 7     1   expected  expect
# 8     2    helpful    help
# 9     3  wonderful  wonder
#10     3 experience  experi
```

Comment: Probably should be `wordStem(word, "english")` unless you want the Porter stemmer.